# Can we create a canonical answer on how to transpose row,col into col,row?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to ask a question on U&L where we could create several implementations of transpose using the various languages (awk, perl, bash, etc.) but this type of question seems as though it would be off topic, yet I and others have answered at least a 1/2 dozen or so of these questions just this week. So it seems like a canonical Q&A to this topic would be valuable.

What's the best way to proceed?

BTW: I can provide references to Q&A's if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we've already got a bunch of them, why do we need another? Post a good answer on one of them that includes methods for all the tools you want (although I don't really see why we need the same solution with a dozen different tools/languages either), and start closing new questions as a duplicate of that one

Comment: The trouble I've seen is that each question is slightly different and people (my self included) will provide single solutions rather than a general one. But I think what you're saying is implement the "ultimate" transpose function in say `awk` and post it as an answer on one of the more general Q's and then reference the heck out it, no?

Comment: @slm Yes. You can throw in implementations in other languages if you want, as long as you include the one(s) the question asked for